# using preg_replace function does not insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use preg_replace function, it works properly but when i insert into database (MYSQL) it is inserted unchanged (My   % " " name is   & sourov, datta.) instead of 
"My name is sourov, datta.". What the reason that database don't insert properly?

```
<?php

$des='My   %   name is   & sourov, datta.';
$des = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\,\.]/', ' ', $des);
echo $des; //output will : My name is sourov, datta.
$data = array(
           'title' => $des,
        );

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it inserting the original string as when I `var_dump()` the data array it showed correctly replaced. I did notice a lot of white space however which you may want to cut down on.

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\,\.]/', ' ', $des);` I really hope, that this is not your way of doing a [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 2):

That pattern produces this output:

```
My         name is     sourov, datta.
```

What you need is this:

```
$des = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9,\.]+/', ' ', $des);
```

Note the `+` following the character group. If you are still getting the original string within your DB then you are not doing things right, but this is not going to be the problem anymore.